# Bootstrap validation isn't working properly with inline form prepended input

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this code for bootstrap validation: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/q5wvGsxQ) and it works great but I am having some problems with prepended inputs.

**Before submission**

[image]

**After submission**

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: the validator is placing the icon in a wrong area.You could change this using plugin API. Give us a fiddle with the error. Reproducing the error in a fiddle would help us to help you better.

Answer (score 1):

I use the 'errorPlacement' for this. Here is an example:

```
validator = $("#form").validate({
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            element.parent().after(error);
        }
});
```

And my html looks like this

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Text</span>
    <input ....>  
</div>
```

So what the errorPlacement does is add the error label after the div (which is the parent of the input element), instead of addding it inside the div after the input.